# Flutter: FutureBuilder NoSuchMethodError isNotEmpty

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I've created a flutter project with FlutterBuilder with ListView.builder which get the data from JSON file (local). I successfully build the app, but just for a second the screen shown like this :

[image: my error]

after that, my app work smoothly.
Here is my code :

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: _isInit ? fetchDoa(context) : Future(null),
                builder: (context, _) {
                  if (doaList.isNotEmpty) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: doaList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        Doa doa = doaList[index];
                        return Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                            child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(doa.judul),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                          DoaPage(
                                            doa: doa,
                                          )));
                                },
                                trailing: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    doa.fav
                                        ? Icons.favorite
                                        : Icons.favorite_border,
                                    color: doa.fav ? Colors.red : null,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                                    doa.fav = !doa.fav;
                                  }),
                                )));
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                })
```

This is the complete preview of my app :

[image]

I need your help, Thank you very much :)

Comment: if (doaList.isNotEmpty) is getting empty at the first

Comment: @JanviPatel do you have any advice for my code so the error fixed?

Comment: need to check your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make builder as

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
 if(snapshot.hasData){
    if (doaList != null && doaList.isNotEmpty){
    // UI
    } else {
    // no data available
  }

 } else {
   // show loader or empty container
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Priyesh for your answer. It's really help me :)

Comment: Keep growing :), If it works then make it right please

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if (doaList.isNotEmpty)
```

into this:

```
if (doaList != null)
```

Comment: I would be better to suggest. INITIALIZE your list. We are heading to safety now.

Comment: wow it's just to need change a line of code and successfully fixed :D
Thank you very much mr. ambiguous :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a null data in the following line:

```
if (doaList.isNotEmpty)
```

and your `FutureBuilder` is slightly incorrect.

You need to update your `FutureBuilder` to something like this:

```
  // Change YourDoaList to your model.
  FutureBuilder<YourDoaList>(
    future: _isInit ? fetchDoa(context) : Future(null),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<YourDoaList> snapshot) {
      Widget widget;
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        // You have succesfully get the data.
        // check if you have correct data here
        YourDoaList items = snapshot.data;

        widget = ListView.builder(
           ...
        );
      } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
        // You've failed get the data
        widget = Text("Failed");
      } else {
        // waiting for data
        widget = CircularProgressIndicator();
      }

      return widget;
    },
  ),
```

See documentation here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I more understand about the FutureBuilder :)

Answer (score 1):

Though there are many good answer. But going by your present code. Just add `{}` where you defined your DAO list.

Like

```
var daoList = [];
```

And one important thing from official docs [Link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

So in your initState , do

```
@override
  void initState() {
    myFuture = getFuture();
    super.initState();
  }
```

and then in futureBuilder.

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: myFuture,
    remaining code
........
```